# Why my site cannot communicate with my server?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, websocket, server

I'm facing an issue with websockets. My site works fine locally but not online. Here is the configuration of the site and the VPS.

[site and server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haYK0.png)

On the homepage, I'm getting the following error message: GET https://play.pierrefeuillearnaque.com/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Additionally, when I make a server call from the site, I get the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined.

I've been going around in circles for a while and can't seem to find a solution.
Please help me.

Comment: Please include your code in the question, rather than linking to an external site, or including an image of the code. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for help if you don't know how.